# jQuery create parent and child elements with one function

Tags: jquery, html

I am able to create split a number of list items using the below, however is it possible to create multiple elements with the same function, so at the moment this,

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
</ul>

$(function(){
    var $bigList = jQuery('.dropdown-menu'), group;
    while((group = $bigList.find('li:lt(5)').remove()).length){
    $('<li/>', {class: ( 'span' ),}).append(group).appendTo('.dropdown-menu');
    }
});
```

creates this,

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="span">
        <li>Stuff</li>
        <li>Stuff</li>
        <li>Stuff</li>
        <li>Stuff</li>
        <li>Stuff</li>
    </li>
    <li class="span">
        <li>Stuff</li>
        <li>Stuff</li>
        <li>Stuff</li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But thats not html compliant, so i would like to give each `li` a child `ul` element, to create,

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="span3">
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>Stuff</li>
            <li>Stuff</li>
            <li>Stuff</li>
            <li>Stuff</li>
            <li>Stuff</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="span">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>Stuff</li>
            <li>Stuff</li>
            <li>Stuff</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just a wild guess here: if you change `.append(group)` to `.append($('<ul />')).append(group)`?

Comment: This is probably _not_ what you want to do, but did you know you can pass complete html fragments to jQuery to construct them?

`$('<ul class="dropdown-menu"><li class="span3"><ul class="dropdown"></ul></li></ul>');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create a new `ul` element to append the `group` to, then append that to your created `li` element:

```
...
var $ul = $('<ul/>');

$ul.append(group);

$('<li/>', {
    class: 'span'
}).append($ul).appendTo('.dropdown-menu');
```

I've also removed the brackets you've wrapped around your class name, as these aren't necessary.

Comment: brilliant thanks, the brackets around the class name were there because in the full script each class has a variable added to it.

Comment: just noticed this seems to put all the groups in one <ul> in the last of the created list items?

Comment: Your `var $ul = ...;` needs to be placed within your loop so that it gets recreated each time.